# How to loop on complex list items in Apple Script

Tags: applescript

I need to loop over this list.
I can see that apple script knows the length of the list and loop 2 times, but I get an error when I try to access and work with items of list1 :

> "Impossible to get item 1 of {BOB:{name:"Bob", place:"london"},
> BILL:{name:"Bill", place:"paris"}}"

Here is the code :

```
set list1 to {BOB:{name:"Bob", place:"london"}, BILL:{name:"Bill", place:"paris"}}
log length of list1
repeat with myItem in list1
    log myItem
end repeat
```

Any idea how to achieve that ?

If the list is a simple one like {"Bob", "Bill"}, it works correctly.

Thanks

Comment: This is actually a **record**, not a list. Enumerating records is pretty tedious in AppleScript. An alternative is `NSDictionary` and AppleScriptObjC.

Comment: NSDictionnary is difficult to be an alternative. This example is simple but IRL I have a complex JSON structure that I read with JSON Helper.  Once read what is the best way to manipulate JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

It works if list1 is casted as a list

```
set list1 to {BOB:{name:"Bob", place:"london"}, BILL:{name:"Bill", place:"paris"}}
log length of list1
repeat with myItem in list1 as list
    log myItem
end repeat
```